# How to obtain right eigenvectors of matrix in R?

Tags: r, function, eigenvector, eigenvalue

***Edition :*** the problem in my question was I've tried to find matrix `S` from [equation 8](http://www.quarchome.org/correlationmatrix.pdf) but this equation have error.

How to directly obtain right eigenvectors of matrix in R ? 'eigen()' gives only left eigenvectors

**Really last edition**, I've made big mess here, but this question is really important for me :

`eigen()` provides some **matrix** of eigenvectors, from function help :

" If ‘r <- eigen(A)’, and ‘V <- r$vectors; lam <- r$values’, then

```
                      A = V Lmbd V^(-1)
```

(up to numerical fuzz), where `Lmbd =diag(lam)`"

that is `A V = V Lmbd`, where V is **matrix** now we check it :

```
set.seed(1)
A<-matrix(rnorm(16),4,4)
Lmbd=diag(eigen(A)$values)
V=eigen(A)$vectors
A%*%V

> A%*%V
                      [,1]                  [,2]          [,3]           [,4]
[1,]  0.0479968+0.5065111i  0.0479968-0.5065111i  0.2000725+0i  0.30290103+0i
[2,] -0.2150354+1.1746298i -0.2150354-1.1746298i -0.4751152+0i -0.76691563+0i
[3,] -0.2536875-0.2877404i -0.2536875+0.2877404i  1.3564475+0i  0.27756026+0i
[4,]  0.9537141-0.0371259i  0.9537141+0.0371259i  0.3245555+0i -0.03050335+0i
> V%*%Lmbd
                      [,1]                  [,2]          [,3]           [,4]
[1,]  0.0479968+0.5065111i  0.0479968-0.5065111i  0.2000725+0i  0.30290103+0i
[2,] -0.2150354+1.1746298i -0.2150354-1.1746298i -0.4751152+0i -0.76691563+0i
[3,] -0.2536875-0.2877404i -0.2536875+0.2877404i  1.3564475+0i  0.27756026+0i
[4,]  0.9537141-0.0371259i  0.9537141+0.0371259i  0.3245555+0i -0.03050335+0i
```

and I would like to find matrix of right eigenvectors `R`,
equation which define matrix of left eigenvectors `L` is :

> ```
> L A  = LambdaM L
> ```

equation which define matrix of right eigenvectors `R` is :

> ```
> A R = LambdaM R
> ```

and eigen() provides only matrix `V`:

> ```
> A V = V Lmbd
> ```

I would like to obtain matrix `R` and `LambdaM` for real matrix `A` which may be negative-definite.

Comment: but transpose gives right eigenvectors of transposed matrix, doesn't it ?

Comment: `eigen()` seems to me to be returning right eigenvectors, as I'd expect. Try this to see that it does: `m <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2); e <- eigen(m); e$values[1]; (m %*% e$vectors[,1])/e$vectors[,1]`.

Comment: from 'eigen' help :      "If ‘r <- eigen(A)’, and ‘V <- r$vectors; lam <- r$values’, then

                              A = V Lmbd V^(-1)                         
     
     (up to numerical fuzz), where Lmbd =‘diag(lam)’", so it is A V = V Lmbd not A V = Lmbd V

Comment: @Ben Bolke, I once again have edited my question

Comment: @BenBolker -- Compare these two to see that your bolded statement isn't true: `W <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2); lambda <- diag(1:2); W %*% lambda; lambda %*% W`. I think the OP's confusion is a (quite understandable) notational one. When **W** is a *vector*, right and left multiplication by the scalar **lambda** are equivalent, but the product is typically written like this: **lamda W**. When **W** is a *matrix*, it must be *right*-multiplied by the matrix **Lambda**, like this: **W Lambda**. (Compare equations (1) and (14) [here, for example](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvector.html)).

Comment: mayby I should delete this question and rewrite it ?

Comment: Well, it looks like what you want is *not* technically the definition of the left eigenvector -- see the MathWorld link that @JoshO'Brien gave -- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvector.html -- the left eigenvector satisfies V A == Lambda V, not A V == Lambda V ... but I, or someone, might answer your question (which is at least well-posed, even if it's not technically describing a left eigenvector matrix).  You could rewrite your question to make the terminology precise (e.g. "*this* is a right eigenvector ... *this* is a left eigenvector .. *this* is what I would like to compute)

Comment: still not quite right!  see the Mathworld site referenced above.  When expressed in terms of a *single eigenvector/eigenvalue pair*, `A r == lambda r` is true (eq. 1). When expressed in terms of the eigenvalue *matrix*, the correct expression is `A R == R Lambda` (eq. 14: in Mathworld's notation, `A X_R == X_R D`). So in fact what `eigen` is giving you *is* the right eigenvector matrix, as conventionally defined.  I think you want something different, which is fine, but please be precise (and double-check my claims since I've already been wrong at least once).

Comment: now I understand ! I need to compute matrix `S` from this paper : http://www.quarchome.org/correlationmatrix.pdf  they call `S` right-hand-side eigensystem

Comment: In fact, now that I look at it more carefully, if `A` and `D` are non-singular I don't think you can solve this.  Consider in general `A X == Lambda X` -- now multiply by `X^{-1}` on the right to get `A == Lambda`.

Comment: hmmm.  Are you sure that isn't a typo in the paper?  I'm hesitant to suggest it, but see my previous comment: what happens if you multiply equation (8) in the paper by `S^{-1}` on the right, assuming `S` is non-singular ???

Comment: I've started to suspect that there is error while rewriting my question because  CS=AS => C=A, so now, what should I do with my question ? you helped me to find an error/errors and solve the problem, so I should accept your answer but my question was ill posted

Comment: I have to admit now that I'm stumped.  It sure looks funny to me.

Comment: I've accepted yout answer, thank you for your help, now I'm going to add next edition to my question, which will show orgin of this mess.

Comment: It seems a bit ridiculous, but I would be tempted to write to the authors and ask if there's a typo, after sanity-checking/re-reading the paper one more time/sleeping on it.  It's the kind of typo that could easily get missed because the definition (8) isn't actually used in subsequent development and because people would might automatically and non-consciously correct it when coding numerical solutions.

Comment: I agree with @BenBolker -- that's gotta be a typo in definition (8).  For just one thing, multiplying both sides from the right by `S^(-1)` gives `C = Lambda`, which isn't generally true at all. (BTW, thanks for linking to the paper -- it helped make a bit more sense of this whole episode!)

Comment: @Josh O'Brien thank for your help ! I've implemented whole section 3 and it works as shown in section 4, there really was a mistake in definition (8).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A worked example.

Default (= *right* eigenvectors):

```
m <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3)
e <- eigen(m)
e1 <- e$vectors
zapsmall((m %*% e1)/e1) ## right e'vec
##          [,1]      [,2] [,3]
## [1,] 16.11684 -1.116844    0
## [2,] 16.11684 -1.116844    0
## [3,] 16.11684 -1.116844    0
```

Left eigenvectors:

```
eL <- eigen(t(m))    
eL1 <- eL$vectors
```

(We have to go to a little more effort since we need
to be multiplying by row vectors on the left; if
we extracted just a single eigenvector, R's ignorance
of row/column vector distinctions would make it
"do the right thing" (i.e. `(eL1[,1] %*% m)/eL1[,1]`
just works).)

```
zapsmall(t(eL1) %*% m/(t(eL1)))
##          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
## [1,] 16.116844 16.116844 16.116844
## [2,] -1.116844 -1.116844 -1.116844
## [3,]  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: I'm out of time for now for answering your edited question.  You can try answering your own question based on what's been posted here so far, or wait for someone else to take a crack at it ...

Answer (score 4):

This should work

Given a matrix A.

```
lefteigen  <-  function(A){
  return(t(eigen(t(A))$vectors))
}
```

Every left eigenvector is the transpose of a right eigenvector of the transpose of a matrix

Comment: They will however not be orthogonal in general.